# The increment of python classes

Tags: python

I want to get total increment through more than two classes.  I wrote bellow codes

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def read(self):
        self.i = inc(self.i)


class C(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def read(self):
        self.i = inc(self.i)


def inc(i):
    i += 1
    return i


class Sub(object):
    count = 0
    l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pp = B(count)
    kk = C(count)
    for row1 in l:
        pp.read()

    for row2 in l:
        kk.read()

k = Sub()
```

I expected the total number is 10.  But, I only get 5
How do I get the total number 10.

Thank you

Comment: The question is very much unclear. can you explain more? what is total number?

Comment: why do you use `class` in `class Sub` if you put code like in function ?

Comment: Why are you using `class Sub` as a function?

Comment: where do you get 5 - I don't see any `print()` which would saw it.

Comment: you have wrong indentations in classes - always put correct code because we don't know if your problem is not in wrong indentations.

Comment: every class has own `self.i` and one class doesn't change value in other class - to get 10 you can do `print( pp.i + kk.i )`

Comment: you should rather keep `i` outside classes and then they can change value in the same variable. OR you could create `class A(object)` with class variabla `i` and then create `class B(A)` and `class C(A)`

Comment: hello!!! Thank you very much for a lot of comments.
The actual codes are long codes.  So, I took the required codes out from the long codes.  So, I made a confusion.  I am very sorry for that.
I revised the def inc(i), which seeks to increase the i through class B as well as class C.  However, when I did debug mode, class B returned finally 5.  Besides, kk.read of class C initialized i, so, again def inc(I) returned same 5.  I wanted totally number 10.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit confusing, but why do you expected the result to be 10?

It seems you are confused about mutable and immutable objects in python. Check [this site](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747) for a good text about it.

---

In the `Sub` class you have a `count` [class variable](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3) that is set to zero. Then you used to initialize the a `B` and a `C` object. Both of these objects have initially the same value and they independently increment their own values five times. Note that the `read` method in classes `B` and `C` assigns a new value to their `i` instance variable.

The result would be different if `count` was an empty list, for instance, and the `read` method appended a value to the list. In that case the `count` variable as well as `self.i` in both classes `B` and `C` would be the same list

Comment: Thank you for comments.  What you said is right.
I am worried about those initialization.  How do I avoid initialization?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create class with class variable (and eventually static method) and then `B` and `C` should inherit from that class and use class variable (and static method) to count it

```
class A(object):
    i = 0

    @staticmethod
    def inc():
        A.i += 1


class B(A):
    def read(self):
        A.i += 1
        #A.inc()
        #self.inc()


class C(A):
    def read(self):
        A.i += 1
        #A.inc()
        #self.inc()


def function():
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    pp = B()
    kk = C()

    for x in data:
        pp.read()
        kk.read()

    print(pp.i, kk.i, A.i)

function()
```

---

Eventually methods `read()` should return how many elements they read (like many other `read()` functions do) and you should add it to `count`

```
class B(object):
    def read(self):
        return 1

class C(object):
    def read(self):
        return 1

def function():
    count = 0

    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    pp = B()
    kk = C()

    for x in data:
        count += pp.read()
        count += kk.read()

    print(count)

function()
```

---

**EDIT:** example using list. It is similar to darcamo answer but it increases value on list instead of appeding new elements.

```
class B(object):

    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def read(self):
        self.i[0] = inc(self.i[0]) # <--- list


class C(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def read(self):
        self.i[0] = inc(self.i[0]) # <--- list


def inc(i):
    i += 1
    return i


def function():
    count = [0] # <--- list

    l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    pp = B(count)
    kk = C(count)

    for row in l:
        pp.read()
        kk.read()

    print(pp.i[0], kk.i[0])

function()
```

Comment: Amazing!!!!
Thank you for sending the codes.  I've never seen such a great story.
But, I need a little bit time to understand the movement to the codes.
Thank you very much again.!!!

Comment: I added example with `count` as list - and then both class update the same value.